# Completar valores de uma coluna com valores da propria coluna em data.table

Tags: r, data.rable-r

Tenho um `data.table()` com as seguintes colunas: **municipio**, **ano** e **pib_per_capta**. (na verdade tenho mais 30 colunas, mas para exemplo acho que só isso basta)

A base está toda preenchida de 2005 a 2018.
Entretanto, para o ano de 2019 o pib_per_capta está como **NA**.

Gostaria de atribuir valor a ele da seguinte maneira: obter a taxa de variação de 2017 e 2018, e multiplicar pelo valor de 2018.

Como isso ficaria?

*Obs: 2019 = (2018/2017) * 2018*
*Obs2: Se souberem como melhorar o título da pergunta, só falar*

Exemplo dos dados:

```
structure(list(municipio = c(110001L, 110001L, 110001L, 110037L, 
110037L, 110037L, 110040L, 110040L, 110040L, 110034L, 110034L, 
110034L), ano = c(2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2017L, 
2018L, 2019L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L), pib_per_capta = c(19081.43, 
21552.47, NA, 23353.6, 21053.93, NA, 14699.7, 15655.57, NA, 15062.51, 
17423.49, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui vai uma solução. Usa uma função `f` para calcular o novo valor do `pib_per_capta` (falta um *i* em *capita*).

```
f <- function(x){
  y <- x[["pib_per_capta"]]
  pib <- tail(y, n = 3)[-3]
  new_pib <- pib[2]^2/pib[1]
  pib <- c(y[-length(y)], new_pib)
  pib
}

dados[, pib_per_capta := f(.SD), by = municipio]
```